# css nth child :after - flip image horizontally

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to take an :after element, which is an image frame and flip the second one in a group of 3 horizontally.

Here's my current css:

```
.photo-frame { 
  position: relative; 
  width: 354px; 
  height: 244px; 
}
.photo-frame:after { 
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  display: block; 
  width: 354px; 
  height: 244px; 
  background: url(images/photo-frame.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
}
.photo-frame img { 
  display: block; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
.photo-frame:nth-child(2):after {
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: FlipH;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="shell">
  <div class="section-body">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="photo-frame">
            <img width="354" height="244" src="/uploads/2014/10/dierks-354x244.jpg" class="attachment-photo-image" alt="dierks" />
          </div><!-- /.photo-frame -->
        </a>
          <div class="top-section-img-title">
            <strong>
              <a href="#">ARTIST NAME</a>
            </strong>
          </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="photo-frame">
            <img width="354" height="244" src="/uploads/2014/10/carrie-354x244.jpg" class="attachment-photo-image" alt="carrie" />
          </div><!-- /.photo-frame -->
        </a>
        <div class="top-section-img-title">
          <strong>
            <a href="#">ARTIST NAME</a>
          </strong>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="photo-frame">
            <img width="354" height="244" src="/uploads/2014/10/luke-354x244.jpg" class="attachment-photo-image" alt="luke" />
          </div><!-- /.photo-frame -->
        </a>
        <div class="top-section-img-title">
          <strong>
            <a href="#">ARTIST NAME</a>
          </strong>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="more">
      <a href="#">VIEW FULL LINEUP HERE</a>
    </div><!-- /.more -->
  </div><!-- /.section-body -->
</div><!-- /.shell -->
```

It's not working however.
I'm fairly new to this nth child selector magic. Can you guys give me a hand?

Comment: Please demo the issue.

Comment: We need to see your HTML as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `.photo-frame` is an **only child** within each `li` so your selector does not match anything. You should also know that `:nth-child()` only selects **elements** not classes or ID's like how you're currently trying.

Because the `li`'s are children elements, and ancestors of each .`photo-frame`, I suggest targeting them with `:nth-child()` instead to select the .`photo-frame` you want to style:

```
li:nth-child(2) .photo-frame:after {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Nice! That makes perfect sense. I'm going to give this a whirl.